# C++ sends virtual key with WM_KEYDOWN on keybd_event()

Tags: c++, keyboard

I would like my program to send this third party virtual key VK_ALOGIN or 0xf7  with WM_KEYDOWN.

So I try the following:

```
keybd_event(0xf7, 0, 0, 0);
```

But the program that receives this keyboard message, it receives only VK_ALOGIN, and not with WM_KEYDOWN.  So is it possible that I can send 0xf7 with WM_KEYDOWN?

Please note that VK_ALOGIN is not Microsoft Virtual Key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Receiver might be looking for keydown, as well as key up. Try sending both.

```
keybd_event( VK_ALOGIN, 0, 0, 0 );
keybd_event( VK_ALOGIN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0 );
```

or

```
keybd_event( VK_ALOGIN, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0 );
keybd_event( VK_ALOGIN, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0 );
```

Edit: I deleted reference to SendInput because now I think it has nothing to do with the question, and I am not sure if I got SendInput right.

Comment: Barmak, what does value 0x45 stand for?

Comment: Phillip, I updated the answer, added link to description. Second parameter is "hardware scan code for the key".

Comment: I shouldn't be putting 0x45 there. The second value is usually ignored. I think it's for VK_NUMLOCK only. I am going to edit and remove it.

Comment: Passing `1` as the first parameter to `SendInput` is not ever not a mistake. Please read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) to understand, why `SendInput` was invented, and which inherent problem of `keybd_event` it solves.

Comment: @IInspectable, did I get SendIput right or wrong? It's probably weird the way I put it in a function with fixed parameter 1, but not wrong. This answer is turning in to a disaster, it might not even have anything to do with the question. I am just going to delete the reference to SendInput.

Comment: `SendInput` is better suited than `keybd_event`. Relevant quote from the documentation: *"These events are not interspersed with other keyboard or mouse input events inserted either by the user (with the keyboard or mouse) or by calls to keybd_event, mouse_event, or other calls to SendInput."* It is absolutely vital to have key down and up events injected as an atomic unit. Of course, the correct way to automate another application is almost always [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx), considering how brittle faking input is.

Comment: Barmak, your first code sample was working for me.  Other app was able to catch VK_ALOGIN with WM_KEYDOWN.  But now after using your newest code, the app only catches VK_ALOGIN, but there is no WM_KEYDOWN.

Comment: LOL, that's great Phillip. I should have just left it.

Comment: Hi Barmak, not sure why.  I try both code samples above, but it only catches the VK_ALOGIN, but not WM_KEYDOWN.  I shouldn't had removed the original sample that I got from you earlier because that was working.

Comment: Phillip, I had made a whole bunch of edits, it's available in the log, you can click the link "edited some hours ago" http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29157070/revisions

Comment: Thanks Barmak.. I have accepted your answer as my solution because it's working.  It's my mistake.